# Open Cart Website not working

Tags: opencart

I have an Opencart website, suddenly it is showing a blank page. Opencart admin is working but the front end is showing nothing no error page noting just blank page. Can any one help me in sorting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your config file present in

```
projectname/config.php
```

double check your paths provided here this occur usually when we provide wrong paths.

Comment: config.php seems perfect all the paths are correct over there.

Comment: Dude i recently solve this issue  i have provided wrong project name in config file check the DIR_APPLICATION path in root config and in admin config the path must be same before admin

Comment: This is admin/ config.php:

Comment: this is admin/config.php: 
// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/abc/public_html/admin/');

Comment: and This is root/config.php: // DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/abc/public_html/catalog/');

Comment: put this in your config file var_dump($_SERVER); see are your paths are same in DOCUMENT_ROOT..

Comment: i putted this and below is the result: { ["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(27) "/home/abc/public_html" ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=> string(0) "" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(27) "/home/abc/public_html"